# How to deserialize object from OData Atom feed?

Tags: wcf, odata, datacontractserializer, atom-feed

I am trying to parse response from an OData REST service. When response is in JSON format, it is easy to use `ReadAsJsonDataContract` method from WCF REST starter kit. However things seem to be more complicated in case the response is an Atom feed. This is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://localhost:64172/BookshopService.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://localhost:64172/BookshopService.svc/Books(89)</id>
  <title type="text"></title>
  <updated>2010-11-08T09:44:21Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="Books" href="Books(89)" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/OrderLines" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="OrderLines" href="Books(89)/OrderLines" />
  <category term="BookshopModel.Books" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">89</d:Id>
      <d:Author>Martin Fowler</d:Author>
      <d:Title>Analysis Patterns</d:Title>
      <d:Price m:type="Edm.Decimal">50.20</d:Price>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

So the actual object is serialized in "content/m:properties" element. And of course this can't be handled by `DataContractSerializer` that expects a different schema.

Does anyone know what technique can be used to deserialize the content of OData atom m:properties element?

Answer (score 3):

WCF Data Services has a client which can be used to consume the responses and materialize CLR object from those. Take a look at the `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext` class and all related classes.
In fact, in VS you can "Add Service Reference" to your OData services and it will generate client-side classes for the services as well as a derived class from the `DataServiceContext` for you to use.
If you already have the client side classes you can use the `DataServiceContext.Execute<T>` method to issue any query and materialize its results into the client side types.

Comment: Vitek, thank you for the answer. I have a service reference to my OData service, and it works very well with LINQ, so I don't even need to manually use DataContractSerializer in my app. So this is mainly for my curiousity: in case I want to have full control and deserialize objects from JSON or AtomPub payload, how do I do it? I managed to achieve it with JSON, but Atom feed seems to be more tricky, because it does not use the original schema. Perhaps there's no simple way to rebuild the object from such feed without going through each individual field?

Comment: I see, currently I'm not aware of a simple way to do this with ATOM payloads. The client library materializer is sometimes close, but it does bring in probably more complexity than you want to. So if you really need to do this, then custom parser based on some XML parsing library (XLinq is easy) is your best option.

Comment: I see. Then I guess I will stick to standard options: using LINQ or Json.