# how to deserialize WCF Data Service object?

Tags: c#, serialization, wcf-data-services

I have the following returned to client from "ServiceOperation" (of a WCF Data Service):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://dd-1620/SampleData.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://dd-1620/SampleData.svc/Customers('1001')</id>
  <title type="text"></title>
  <updated>2011-06-21T18:42:05Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="Customer" href="Customers('1001')" />
  <category term="Customer" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:MasterCustomerId>1001</d:MasterCustomerId>
      <d:SubCustomerId>0</d:SubCustomerId>
      <d:FirstName>Jag</d:FirstName>
      <d:LastName>Chat</d:LastName>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

We get the above when executing the following:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUri);
req.Credentials = cache;
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/xml";
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
string sResp = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

When I try to deserialize it using the following:

```
DataContractSerializer dc = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Customer));
return (Customer)dc.ReadObject(new System.IO.MemoryStream(sResp.ToByteArrayUTF8()));
```

I get the following error:

**Error in line 1 position 249. Expecting element 'Customer' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SampleSvcRef'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'entry', namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'.**

UPDATE:

The Customer class generated using service reference is as follows:

```
[global::System.Data.Services.Common.EntitySetAttribute("Customers")]
[global::System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceKeyAttribute("MasterCustomerId")]
public partial class Customer : global::System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new Customer object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="masterCustomerId">Initial value of MasterCustomerId.</param>
    /// <param name="subCustomerId">Initial value of SubCustomerId.</param>
    /// <param name="lastName">Initial value of LastName.</param>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    public static Customer CreateCustomer(string masterCustomerId, string subCustomerId, string lastName)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.MasterCustomerId = masterCustomerId;
        customer.SubCustomerId = subCustomerId;
        customer.LastName = lastName;
        return customer;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for Property MasterCustomerId in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    public string MasterCustomerId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._MasterCustomerId;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnMasterCustomerIdChanging(value);
            this._MasterCustomerId = value;
            this.OnMasterCustomerIdChanged();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("MasterCustomerId");
        }
    }
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    private string _MasterCustomerId;
    partial void OnMasterCustomerIdChanging(string value);
    partial void OnMasterCustomerIdChanged();
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for Property SubCustomerId in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    public string SubCustomerId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._SubCustomerId;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnSubCustomerIdChanging(value);
            this._SubCustomerId = value;
            this.OnSubCustomerIdChanged();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SubCustomerId");
        }
    }
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    private string _SubCustomerId;
    partial void OnSubCustomerIdChanging(string value);
    partial void OnSubCustomerIdChanged();
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for Property FirstName in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._FirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnFirstNameChanging(value);
            this._FirstName = value;
            this.OnFirstNameChanged();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    private string _FirstName;
    partial void OnFirstNameChanging(string value);
    partial void OnFirstNameChanged();
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for Property LastName in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LastName;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnLastNameChanging(value);
            this._LastName = value;
            this.OnLastNameChanged();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    private string _LastName;
    partial void OnLastNameChanging(string value);
    partial void OnLastNameChanged();
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    public event global::System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new global::System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: paste your Customer object. It sounds like you are missing the DataContract and DataMember attributes.

Comment: The Customer class (at client) is automatically generated by proxy when adding service reference.  On the server, Customer is an entity generated from Entity Framework.

Comment: Can you see a a DataContract attribute at the top? If not you might need a buddy class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109785/why-are-buddy-classes-used-for-validation

Comment: sorry, missed the fact you are using the generated client. Should you not be using that to query the methods? It will call+deserialise automatically rather than you needing to use a HttpGet

Comment: Just updated my post with the proxy 'Customer' created by Service reference.  But, I don't have any problems with Customer class.  I use "Customers" in Uri to get list of "Customers" and everything works fine (even the CRUD).  This error is only with Service Operation and that too I am using traditional "WebRequest" way to execute it.

Comment: You are right.  But, for my application, I have to send XML (in body) using POST method.  That is the reason, I have to go with HttpGet.  Everything works fine and the data also comes to client correctly, but, I could not deserialize it to "Customer" entity (at client).

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to say is that the XML above is not a `Customer` object. When consuming the WCF service you should use the ServiceNameClient client = new ServiceNameClient("your http end point"). Then call your method. Or create a new class as below that would allow you to deserialise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is answered here [How to deserialize object from OData Atom feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124196/how-to-deserialize-object-from-odata-atom-feed)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The `Customer` object will need to look something like this.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyEntities.Customer))]
[DataContract(Name = "entry")]
public partial Customer
{
  [DataMember(Name = "id")]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "title")]
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Checkout this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx

Comment: Setting the name property is unnecessary.

Comment: Just updated my post with the proxy 'Customer' created by Service reference.  But, I don't have any problems with Customer class.  I use "Customers" in Uri to get list of "Customers" and everything works fine (even the CRUD).  This error is only with Service Operation and that too I am using traditional "WebRequest" way to execute it.